# How to find difference between two times in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time

So I need to find the difference between two given times from an html form in javascript.

So far, my code has been returning "undefined".

Here's the code.
the times are from a datetime-local input in the form, so they're in the format of mm/dd/yyyy 00:00 AM/PM

```
function ready() {

    submit.onclick = function () { 
        var timeo = document.getElementById("first");
        var timet = document.getElementById("second");
        console.log(timeo);
        console.log(timet);
        var diff = Math.abs(new Date(timet) - new Date(timeo));

        let el = document.createElement('p')
        el.innerHTML = "Your elapsed time was: " + diff.getTime;
        console.log("worked");
        results.append(el);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

Please help!

Comment: What is `.getTime`?

Comment: When one Date is subtracted from another, the result is the difference in milliseconds so `"Your elapsed time was: " + diff + " milliseconds."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*timeo* and *timet* are the elements themselves, you should take the ***value*** from the elements:

```
var timeo = document.getElementById("first").value;
var timet = document.getElementById("second").value;
```